# Is there a faster way to filter out rows or delete rows from a Pyspark dataframe? I tried .where and .filter but they are too

Tags: python, pyspark

I am running a fuzzy matching workstream using the RapidFuzz library in Pyspark. The function completes computation on 3.4 billion records in about 3 minutes but it takes about 3 hours to filter out the zeros. I tried `.filter` and `.where` they both produced the same run times. There has to be a faster method, if the fuzzy matching can be done in 3 minutes, then it should take less time to filter out the 0s.

A sample code:

```
l2 = l1.where(l1.l_levensthien != 0)
```

AND I did

```
l2 = l1.where(l1.l_levensthien > 80)
```

They both take years to run.

I can include the function code as well.

Comment: Was the `3 min` for fuzzing matching computed after invoking an action on the dataframe? Remember that Spark is lazy and computation only runs on invocation of an action. If this is the case, then can you share the execution plan for `l2` using `l2.explain()` and `l1rdd.getNumPartitions()` to see if parallelism is applied apropriately.

Comment: Hello snithish, yes I called a count() function and a unique count to ensure that it gets called, I made the mistake early in development when I realized it Spark is lazy. The 3 mins is after running the fuzzy matching function on a pair of names and storing the fuzzy matching scores. When filtering out that is where the time is taking years. I did a number of tests to ensure that it was in fact the filtering that is taking a long time.  That is a good call out though, thank you.